# django-allauth accounts/signup gets [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: django, django-allauth

I know that there are a lot of answers to this issue say that I should probably try running my server on another port like so: `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080`  I have tried that didn't fix it.  I have turned off my windows Norton firewall:

[image]

I have started PyCharm as administrator.   The thing that make me think these solutions were not going to work for me was that other API endpoints work fine:  `http://localhost:8000/accounts/login/` works and `http://localhost:8000/accounts/logout/` works too.  But when I fill out the form and POST my data to `http://localhost:8000/accounts/signup` I get this error:

```
OSError at /accounts/signup/
[WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/signup/
Django Version: 2.2.7
Exception Type: OSError
Exception Value:    
[WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
```

Can someone please tell me what I am missing here?

Answer (score 7):

You are using the wrong system for mailing ! for test and in  localhoset set it as below:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

in settings.py

Answer (score 4):

Encountered the same issue with an identical setup.
Apparently has something to do with sending a confirmation email.
Turning off email verification fixed the problem for me:

```
# settings.py
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "none"
```